# Why can't poor countries just print more money?

Tags: money-transfer, income, economics

I know this is a really silly question that is really obvious, but what's stopping a country from just printing out a few more billion of their own currency and then using that money to buy goods from other countries? Is there a certain rule they have to follow? And what are the impacts to the economy if they did do that?

Comment: This question is more apt on economics.se and would be offtopic here.

Comment: @Dheer could u kindly transfer this question over there,you could flag it to moderator :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing money doesn't mean that their wealth increases. It just devalues the money they already have. So it will just take more money to buy goods from another country.

Printing money will also lead to over inflation which has its own set of problems such as:

- Higher interest rates
- People will buy durable goods to store wealth such as gold
- [Cost-push inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost-push_inflation)

Comment: Other examples: US dollar worth 35 quadrillion Zimbabwe dollars http://www.foxnews.com/world/2015/06/12/one-us-dollar-z35-quadrillion-as-zimbabwe-phases-out-old-currency.html Currency collectors have other examples: http://www.collectorscurrency.com/collections/inflation-notes also http://polkadotpapershop.com/index.php?ka=inflation+currency (not an endorsement, just google results). Also google "wheelbarrow full of currency to buy bread" (no quotes). There's even a humorous (maybe true) anecdote:a man left a wheelbarrow full of money outside.. someone stole the wheelbarrow and left the money.